# Dropdownlist in razor cshtml with model and viewmodel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code. The model is an Asset. However, what I want is to assign a user for each Asset in View Model through `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserFromTable, new SelectList(Model.UsersFromTable, "UserName", "UserName"))`.

The thing is that I tried appropriate `SelectList<>` etc., but I don't know how to assign users from the dropdownlist in users column to assets in ViewModel. Another thing is that I don't receive my selection in ViewModel after Post. I can pass there some checkbox values but not the selections from the above dropdownlist.

I read some posts on stackoverflow and found out that some similar tasks require foreach. There is already one foreach loop in the code. I believe I should work on `var item in Model.Assets` somehow. I also have a separate CRUD Edit cshtml page for editing one single Asset but I want to save changes in user dropdownlist to all Assets on the current page.

Is it possible and how can I do it?

```
@Html.Partial("AssetsFiltering", Model.AssetsFilteringVM)
@foreach (var item in Model.Assets)
{
    <tr class="data-rows">
        <td>@Html.Span(item.Id)</td>
        ....
        <td>                       
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserFromTable, new SelectList(Model.UsersFromTable, "UserName", "UserName"))
        </td>
```

Comment: How does your view model class definition looks like ? Are you using same view model as the parameter of your http post action method ?

Comment: use ViewData to assign values to your dropdown list and name the dropdown list the same name as the property that will contain the selected value on your POST method

Comment: But ViewModel contains public IEnumerable<Asset> Assets { get; set; } and  public IEnumerable<UsersTable> UsersFromTable { get; set; }. How to bind the values from DropDownList to IEnumerable<Asset> Assets through Post action?

Comment: Finally I found the answer : @for(int i=0; i < Model.Assets.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr class="data-rows">
                    <td>
                        **@Html.Span(Model.Assets.ElementAt(i).Id)
                    </td>                                                                 **                            ... and then  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => **model.UsersFromTable[i].UserName**, new SelectList(Model.UsersFromTable, "UserName", "UserName"))